# Virtual android devices don't appear in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium Studio 3.2.1 on a Windows 7 x64 and wanted to launch a project in android emulator. Therefore, I installed the android sdk-bundle, put it in my system path and created an AVD. The AVD works fine when starting it directly. However, I'm not able to choose my AVD in Titanium. Only device definitions, e.g. "Galaxy Nexus", "Nexus 4" are displayed but not the devices I created. So I can't run or debug a project at all. By selecting one of the definitions (e.g. "Galaxy Nexus"), the following output is shown:

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 255
```

Any ideas? I also have Titanium Studio installed on a Mac OS X and everything works fine there.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Very frustrating... On Mac OS X there are no problems - I simply create an AVD choose it for run/debug. But on Windows it still doesn't work.

Comment: My problem was related to Android SDK Tools version. I had version 22.6.2 which apparently only works using Titanium sdk 3.2.3 (alpha). I downgraded Android SDK Tools to 22.3 and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I solved the problem by reinstalling Titanium Studio and upgrading NodeJS packages with:

```
npm update -g
```